# Send a message via LinkedIn API V2

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am looking for sample code or documentation around sending messages throuhg the LinkedIn API.
The examples in official documentation do not work for me:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/communications/messages

I get a 403 and I am wondering if it is my code, the fact that I try to send a message to myself or a missing permission.

If somebody has a link to a sample page or documentation for python this would be great.

Comment: from that page, `Usage of this API is restricted to approved partners, subject to limitations via API agreement.` -- do you have such approval & agreement?

Comment: You are correct, I do not have a separate agreement. I was focusing on the requirements section to get a test setup.